# How to write once more #define in line

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, turbo-c++

I want to have a line of code over a `#define`
But this will not be allowed Turbo C++.

This is pictured below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [uupload.ir](http://uupload.ir/files/47na_define.jpg))</sub>

Comment: You can't have two #define on the same line.

Comment: Don't define both of them on the same line, if you define them on different lines, it will work. ( oh and a word of advice, don't use TurboC++, it's ancient, use some other IDE like Ccde Blocks )

Comment: Why would someone still use TurboC++?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code! Edit the question to include the actual code ***as text***!

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm use VS IDE
But for a challenge in university  should I use Turbo C++
I know you have every line is simply a #define
I know there was a line once more  the #define ?

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one preprocessor directive on a single line. You'll have to put each on a separate line.

```
#define aaa for
#define bbb while
```

Then stop abusing the preprocessor like that. Then get a modern compiler, if you want to learn a useful dialect of C++.

Comment: i know ,
I want to be in a line once more the #define !? /!!

Comment: @Mahdi.lpr: I don't know what you mean. If you want more than one in a single line, then you can't do that; you'll have to put one on each line. If you want the macro expansion to define a second macro, then you can't do that; the preprocessor is very primitive, and won't let you get too clever with it.